# byobu renames windows in ssh session

Tags: ssh, byobu

I connect to a remote computer with `ssh` and start a `byobu` session on the remote machine. Whenever I change the directory in a byobu window, the window gets renamed to `username@remote-pc:~/.../.../...`. When I rename the window using `F8` the name persists until the next `cd`.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem on Fedora.

In each bash session, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set by default in `/etc/bashrc` to `__vte_prompt_command`

`man bash` says

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
```

`__vte_prompt_command` is defined in `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh`

`type __vte_prompt_command` gives

```
__vte_prompt_command is a function
__vte_prompt_command () 
{ 
    local pwd='~';
    [ "$PWD" != "$HOME" ] && pwd=${PWD/#$HOME\//\~\/};
    printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${pwd}" "$(__vte_osc7)"
}
```

to prevent this, you could add `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` after sourcing `/etc/bashrc` in your `~/.bashrc`

You may also want to do this only inside a byobu session, you could test byobu environment variable for that (`BYOBU_RUN_DIR`?)

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is for zsh users.**

I've had this happen to me twice now with zsh. Frustrating. Posting here so I can search for the solution in the future (and hopefully help any other lost souls).

In `~/.zshrc` you will find

```
# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.                                                                                                          
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

Uncomment out `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` so it looks like

```
# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.                                                                                                          
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

no worries, future me

Comment: i knew this would come in handy

Answer (score 0):

When using tmux, you can prevent any program from renaming the window by adding the following to `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```